# Upload do meu site para no meio do caminho

Tags: php

Eu criei um site de imobiliária, quando o corretor vai subir fotos no imóvel, e estas são de alta resolução pesando em torno de 2~5mb, ele para de subir, trava por exemplo em 83%.
Isto pode ser o problema do plugin que eu adicionei, ou o servidor está limitando a conexão ?
Ps. Imagens de menor tamanho sobem 100%.

Comment: Está enviando via Ajax? Qual api/plugin usa para isto? Dê detalhes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O php vem por padrão no servidor permitindo um tamanho máximo de upload, e possui um tempo limite também, eles podem ser alterados pela configuração inicial:

Para o tamanho:

1 - Abra o arquivo `php.ini`

2 - Ache as linhas com `'upload_max_filesize'` e `'post_max_filesize'`

3 - Altere os seus valores pra algum que seja o suficiente para o tamanho das imagens.

---

Para o tempo:

1 - Abra o arquivo `php.ini`

2 - Ache a linha `'set_time_limit'`

3 - Modifique seu valor (segundos) para um valor satisfatório.

[Fonte](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)

Comment: Pode estar certo, mas a pergunta é tão ampla que não acho uma boa responder isto, pode ser qualquer problema além dos citados, até mesmo bug em uma API de upload via javascript, o AP não informou as tecnologias que usa, logo é um tanto quanto improvável afirmar se é isto ou não. Nessas horas pessoalmente penso que o melhor é votar pra fechar e aguardar o AP fornecer detalhes relevantes.